# Integration testing with in-memory IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I have an API that uses IdentityServer4 for token validation.
I want to unit test this API with an in-memory TestServer. I'd like to host the IdentityServer in the in-memory TestServer.

I have managed to create a token from the IdentityServer.

This is how far I've come, but I get an error "Unable to obtain configuration from http://localhost:54100/.well-known/openid-configuration"

The Api uses [Authorize]-attribute with different policies. This is what I want to test.

Can this be done, and what am I doing wrong?
I have tried to look at the source code for IdentityServer4, but have not come across a similar integration test scenario.

```cs
protected IntegrationTestBase()
{
    var startupAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

    _contentRoot = SolutionPathUtility.GetProjectPath(@"<my project path>", startupAssembly);
    Configure(_contentRoot);
    var orderApiServerBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot(_contentRoot)
        .ConfigureServices(InitializeServices)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
    orderApiServerBuilder.Configure(ConfigureApp);
    OrderApiTestServer = new TestServer(orderApiServerBuilder);

    HttpClient = OrderApiTestServer.CreateClient();
}

private void InitializeServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_contentRoot, "idsvr3test.pfx"), "idsrv3test");
    services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.IssuerUri = "http://localhost:54100";
        })
        .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
        .AddInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
        .AddInMemoryUsers(Users.Get())
        .SetSigningCredential(cert);
        
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(OrderApiConstants.StoreIdPolicyName, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new StoreIdRequirement("storeId")));
    });
    services.AddSingleton<IPersistedGrantStore, InMemoryPersistedGrantStore>();
    services.AddSingleton(_orderManagerMock.Object);
    services.AddMvc();
}

private void ConfigureApp(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
    var options = new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = _appsettings.IdentityServerAddress,
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

        ScopeName = _appsettings.IdentityServerScopeName,
        AutomaticAuthenticate = false
    };
    app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(options);
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

And in my unit-test:

```cs
private HttpMessageHandler _handler;
const string TokenEndpoint = "http://localhost/connect/token";
public Test()
{
    _handler = OrderApiTestServer.CreateHandler();
}

[Fact]
public async Task LeTest()
{
    var accessToken = await GetToken();
    HttpClient.SetBearerToken(accessToken);

    var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.GetAsync("stores/11/orders/asdf"); // Fails on this line

}

private async Task<string> GetToken()
{
    var client = new TokenClient(TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret", innerHttpMessageHandler: _handler);

    var response = await client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("TheMOON.OrderApi");

    return response.AccessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you probably need to make a test double fake for your authorization middleware depending on how much functionality you want. So basically you want a middleware that does everything that the Authorization middleware does minus the back channel call to the discovery doc.

IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation is a wrapper around two middlewares. The `JwtBearerAuthentication` middleware, and the `OAuth2IntrospectionAuthentication` middleware. Both of these grab the discovery document over http to use for token validation. Which is a problem if you want to do an in-memory self-contained test.

If you want to go through the trouble you will probably need to make a fake version of `app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication` that doesnt do the external call that fetches the discovery document. It only populates the HttpContext principal so that your [Authorize] policies can be tested.

Check out how the meat of IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation looks [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/IdentityServerAuthenticationMiddleware.cs). And follow up with a look at how JwtBearer Middleware looks [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lutando. Your first answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: ah ok @emedbo I thought it may be a bit much to make the fake test double. But it works :)

Comment: The problem with this apprach is that if you want your continuous integration system to run your integration tests, that requires integrating this authentication spoofing into your release build. That is potentially a really dangerous situation. The alternative of having an actual IdentityServer service that provides dummy authentication for the integration test scenario seems massively preferable.

Comment: @Neutrino, I'm a little confused, if we use the WebApplicationFactory to create the TestServer, then we're not integrating anything into our release build, isn't that the case?

Comment: @LiamFleming When I first tried this approach I used an authentication spoofing middleware that was implemented in the webservice itself and activated by a configuration setting. This was risky as if the configuration setting could accidentally (or otherwise) became enabled on the live system.

Comment: We refactored this so that the spoofing middleware was defined in the test assembly itself and applied by overriding IServiceCollection.AddAuthentication in the test assembly. Since the test assembly is not deployed in the release build there was no way this could be enabled accidentally.

Comment: @Neutrino Makes sense, I solved it with something similar, thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 29):

You were on the right track with the code posted in your initial question.

The **IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions** object has properties to override the default **HttpMessageHandlers** it uses for back channel communication.

Once you combine this with the **CreateHandler()** method on your **TestServer** object you get:

```cs
//build identity server here

var idBuilder = new WebBuilderHost();
idBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
//...

TestServer identityTestServer = new TestServer(idBuilder);

var identityServerClient = identityTestServer.CreateClient();

var token = //use identityServerClient to get Token from IdentityServer

//build Api TestServer
var options = new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5001",

    // IMPORTANT PART HERE
    JwtBackChannelHandler = identityTestServer.CreateHandler(),
    IntrospectionDiscoveryHandler = identityTestServer.CreateHandler(),
    IntrospectionBackChannelHandler = identityTestServer.CreateHandler()
};

var apiBuilder = new WebHostBuilder();

apiBuilder.ConfigureServices(c => c.AddSingleton(options));
//build api server here

var apiClient = new TestServer(apiBuilder).CreateClient();
apiClient.SetBearerToken(token);

//proceed with auth testing
```

This allows the **AccessTokenValidation** middleware in your Api project to communicate directly with your In-Memory **IdentityServer** without the need to jump through hoops.

As a side note, for an Api project, I find it useful to add **IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions** to the services collection in **Startup.cs** using **TryAddSingleton** instead of creating it inline:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = Configuration.IdentityServerAuthority(),
        ScopeName = "api1",
        ScopeSecret = "secret",
        //...,
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions>()

    app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(options);

    //...
}
```

This allows you to register the **IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions** object in your tests without having to alter the code in the Api project.

Comment: Thanks @JamesFera! I was tearing my hair trying to get this working. I use a slightly modyfied TestFixture from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing and it works great.

Comment: Thanks @JamesFera ... this worked for me. Slight code changes, which I have posted in a separate answer for others to use.

Comment: using the backchannelhandler - that was gold!

Comment: I could not make it work, I get http 302 redirect, any idea?

Comment: In 2020, .NET Core 3, maybe you are here because you need [this link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3666) or because you need AddAuthentication.

Comment: I would literally kill for a full example on how to do this. I simply cannot figure out how to do it from what you wrote there. Plus looks like IdentityServer4 has some changes so something things need to be modified (eg the IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions handlers)

Comment: @heringer unfortunately there is not enough information in that post to figure it out. I mean I tried but with no clear example I'm just shooting in the wind.

Answer (score 9):

I understand there is a need for a more complete answer than what @james-fera posted. I have learned from his answer and made a github project consisting of a test project and API project. The code should be self-explanatory and not hard to understand.

https://github.com/emedbo/identityserver-test-template

The `IdentityServerSetup.cs` class https://github.com/emedbo/identityserver-test-template/blob/master/tests/API.Tests/Config/IdentityServerSetup.cs can be abstracted away e.g. NuGetted away, leaving the base class `IntegrationTestBase.cs`

The essences is that can make the test IdentityServer work just like a normal IdentityServer, with users, clients, scopes, passwords etc. I have made the DELETE method [Authorize(Role="admin)] to prove this.

Instead of posting code here, I recommend read @james-fera's post to get the basics then pull my project and run tests.

IdentityServer is such a great tool, and with the ability to use the TestServer framework it gets even better.

Comment: If you are still up for it, would like to see the project you mention. I am currently trying to do something similar to what you describe.

Comment: Have you tried what @james-fera posted above? If not, I'd try it first, as my solution requires a lot more code.

Comment: I tried it, and it did not work. But then I found a configuration error in my identityserver setup. Once fixed, @james-fera's suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I will definitely help you get started :-)

Answer (score 4):

We stepped away from trying to host a mock IdentityServer and used dummy/mock authorizers as suggested by others here.

Here's how we did that in case it's useful:

Created a function which takes a type, creates a test Authentication Middleware and adds it to the DI engine using Configure**Test**Services (so that it's called **after** the call to Startup.)

```cs
internal HttpClient GetImpersonatedClient<T>() where T : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        var _apiFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();

        var client = _apiFactory
            .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddAuthentication("Test")
                        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, T>("Test", options => { });
                });
            })
            .CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            });

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Test");

        return client;
    }
```

Then we create what we called 'Impersonators' (AuthenticationHandlers) with the desired roles to mimic users with roles (We actually used this as a base class, and create derived classes based on this to mock different users):

```cs
public abstract class FreeUserImpersonator : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public Impersonator(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        base.claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "FreeUser"));
    }

    protected List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "Test");

        var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

Finally, we can perform our integration tests as follows:

```cs
// Arrange
HttpClient client = GetImpersonatedClient<FreeUserImpersonator>();

// Act
var response = await client.GetAsync("api/things");

// Assert
Assert.That.IsSuccessful(response);
```

Comment: While I ended up implementing mine slightly different, Liam's idea to move away from the complexities of mocking the identity server to using AuthHandlers saved my sanity.  I used some of his ideas in conjunction with this article: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/11/mocking-authenticated-users.aspx

Comment: the code does not compile: the `Impersonator` constructor does not match the `FreeUserImpersonator` class name, and there is no `base.claims`. Also it is abstract and there is a "Cannot instantiate ... for service type" message.

Answer (score 3):

Test API startup:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public static HttpMessageHandler BackChannelHandler { get; set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //accept access tokens from identityserver and require a scope of 'Test'
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost",
            BackchannelHttpHandler = BackChannelHandler,
            ...
        });

        ...
    }
}
```

Assigning the AuthServer.Handler to TestApi BackChannelHandler in my unit test project:

```cs
    protected TestServer AuthServer { get; set; }
    protected TestServer MockApiServer { get; set; }
    protected TestServer TestApiServer { get; set; }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        ...
        AuthServer = TestServer.Create<AuthenticationServer.Startup>();
        TestApi.Startup.BackChannelHandler = AuthServer.CreateHandler();
        TestApiServer = TestServer.Create<TestApi.Startup>();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track! Setting `BackChannelHandler` on the `JwtBearerOptions` passed to `services.AddJwtBearer()` in my API project to value of `TestServer.CreateHandler()` for the IdentityServer TestServer was key for me. For authentication to pass I also had to set `TestServer.BaseAddress` for the IdentityServer TestServer to the same URL as `JwtBearerOptions.Authority`

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a handler using the `TestServer` that is configured to use `IdentityServer4`. Samples can be found [here](https://github.com/cleancodelabs/IdentityServer4.Contrib.AspNetCore.Testing/blob/master/test/IdentityServer4.Contrib.AspNetCore.Testing.Tests/IdentityServerProxyTests.cs).

I created a [nuget-package](https://github.com/cleancodelabs/IdentityServer4.Contrib.AspNetCore.Testing) available to install and test using the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2) library and the latest version of `IdentityServer4` for this purpose.

It encapsulates all the infrastructure code necessary to build an appropriate `WebHostBuilder` which is then used to create a `TestServer` by generating the `HttpMessageHandler` for the `HttpClient` used internally.

Comment: This might be just what I'm looking for. Am I correct in thinking that if I add this nuget package I should be able to simply replace WebHostBuilder with  IdentityServerWebHostBuilder when creating a `TestServer` and `client`. Could you show how that would look or point me to a sample please.

Comment: Hey, you find samples here:
https://github.com/cleancodelabs/IdentityServer4.Contrib.AspNetCore.Testing/blob/master/test/IdentityServer4.Contrib.AspNetCore.Testing.Tests/IdentityServerProxyTests.cs

I hope they help!

Comment: Thanks. I can see from the samples how to create in memory `IdentityServer4` instances but I wonder if you could show how to make the `TestServer` for my api use the in memory `IdentityServer4` instance instead of the 'real' one.

Comment: I have sample here on one of my pet-projects:
https://github.com/alsami/etdb-userservice-aspnet-core/blob/master/test/Etdb.UserService.Bootstrap.Tests/Mocking/ApiServerStartup.cs#L65

It's a little bit different since I am using `HttpClientFactory` to do the requests. There is one tests already working like that. Maybe you will want to dig into it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me because they rely on 1) a static field to hold your HttpHandler and 2) the Startup class to have knowledge that it may be given a test handler.  I've found the following to work, which I think is a lot cleaner.

First create an object that you can instantiate before your TestHost is created.  This is because you won't have the HttpHandler until after the TestHost is created, so you need to use a wrapper.

```cs
public class TestHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public TestHttpMessageHandler(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.Information($"Sending HTTP message using TestHttpMessageHandler. Uri: '{request.RequestUri.ToString()}'");

        if (WrappedMessageHandler == null) throw new Exception("You must set WrappedMessageHandler before TestHttpMessageHandler can be used.");
        var method = typeof(HttpMessageHandler).GetMethod("SendAsync", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var result = method.Invoke(this.WrappedMessageHandler, new object[] { request, cancellationToken });
        return await (Task<HttpResponseMessage>)result;
    }

    public HttpMessageHandler WrappedMessageHandler { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```cs
var testMessageHandler = new TestHttpMessageHandler(logger);

var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
...
                        services.PostConfigureAll<JwtBearerOptions>(options =>
                        {
                            options.Audience = "http://localhost";
                            options.Authority = "http://localhost";
                            options.BackchannelHttpHandler = testMessageHandler;
                        });
...

var server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
var innerHttpMessageHandler = server.CreateHandler();
testMessageHandler.WrappedMessageHandler = innerHttpMessageHandler;
```