# Integration testing with IdentityServerAuthentication IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-1.0, identityserver4

Like this question "[Integration testing with in-memory IdentityServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390339/integration-testing-with-in-memory-identityserver)", I would like to make some integration test against my implementation of IdentityServer4.

I've followed this tutorial [IDENTITYSERVER4, WEB API AND ANGULAR2 IN A SINGLE ASP.NET CORE PROJECT](https://damienbod.com/2016/10/01/identityserver4-webapi-and-angular2-in-a-single-asp-net-core-project/) to add an API for manage users in the same project as my IdentityServer4.

But the integration testing failed because the IdentityServer try to call the discoveryEndpoint with an HTTP request.

So in this question "[Integration testing with in-memory IdentityServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390339/integration-testing-with-in-memory-identityserver)" @emedbo create a FakeAccessTokenValidation, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little bit of help by reading the ASP.Net Core Identity Code, I've adapted a Middleware to fake a user without needed authentication.

More on this github repo https://github.com/waldo2188/fake-authentication-jwtbearer

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed